# Assembly segmentation-fault

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, segmentation-fault, cpu-registers

So, I have this program that is meant to do the following: with 3 Arrays, copy the values of the first Array that are not present in the second one to the third.
The problem is that I keep getting the "Segmentation Fault" error when I try to compile it, and when I use gdb the program works fine.

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "asm.h"

short int *ptrvec1;
short int *ptrvec2;
int *ptrvec3;
int numElem = 1;

int
main(void)
{

    short int vec1[2] = { 1, 3 };
    short int vec2[2] = { 1, 5 };
    int vec3[5];

    ptrvec1 = vec1;             //vetor1 apontado por ptrvec1
    ptrvec2 = vec2;             //vetor2 apontado por ptrvec2
    ptrvec3 = vec3;             //vetor3 apontado por ptrvec3

    int numElementos;

    numElementos = diferentes();

    printf("\nNumber of elements:  %i\n", numElementos);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", vec1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Asm.s

```
.global ptrvec1
.global ptrvec2
.global ptrvec3
.global numElem
.global diferentes

diferentes:
    mov ptrvec1, %esi
    mov ptrvec2, %edi
    mov ptrvec3, %esp

    movl $0, %ebp           #contador1 = 0
    movl $0, %edx           #contador2 = 0
    mov $0, %cx
    #movl $0, %ebx
    mov $0, %eax            #limpa registo de eax

ciclo1:
    movw (%esi), %cx
    cmp %cx, (%edi)
    jne verificar1

    mov $0, %cx
    incl %ebp
    add $2, %esi
    movl $0, %edx           #contador2 = 0  
    jmp ciclo1

verificar1: 
    cmp numElem, %edx
    je adicionar_vetor3

    incl %edx
    add $2, %edi
    mov $0, %cx

    jmp ciclo1

adicionar_vetor3:
    mov $0, %cx
    movl $0, %edx           #contador2 = 0
    mov (%esi), %cx
    mov %cx, (%esp)
    add $4, %esp

    incl %eax
    cmp numElem, %ebp
    je fim

    incl %ebp
    jmp ciclo1

fim:
    ret
```

Make file (I think he's fine, but doesn't hurt to drop it here)

```
main: main.o asm.o
    gcc -Wall -g main.o asm.o -o main

main.o: main.c asm.h
    gcc -Wall -g -c main.c

asm.o: asm.s
    gcc -Wall -g -c asm.s

run: main
    ./main

clean:
    rm *.o main
```

Comment: Storing an arbitrary value into `esp` seems bad. Segfault-ily bad.

Comment: I changed it to ebx and now it works. I still get the Segmentation-fault error but it prints the correct values.

Comment: Add a `pusha` and `popa` to the start and end of your function, respectively. This will store the GPRs' values on the stack. If they aren't captured, the compiler will have no idea about the registers being modified and will produce bad code. Best would be to use [Extended Assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) anyway. Still, **do not** change `esp`'s value.

Comment: You don't need to include `asm.h` into your linking process. Let the preprocessor do that.

Comment: asm.h isn't included in the link, but it is listed as something that, if it changes, requires a rebuild of main.o.